# drupal 7 unable to login the Admin area

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am unable to login to my drupal 7 website.

I did recover try to recover the password through email but when I try to login through the link provided in that email it gives access denied error.

I have followed the instruction given on this page http://drupal.org/node/1023428 but still no luck.

This issue started when I raised a ticket to my web hosting provider regarding the performance issue, there reply is included below, might help you understanding  the problem

> When attempting to load http://digitalexperts.net from our location, it took several seconds longer than it should have to load. Upon investigating the slowness, I found two issues with the domain's DNS zone. First, the NS records for the domain were set to the server's default shared nameservers rather than the private ones that you appear to have set through your registrar (ns1.dxrise.com and ns2.dxrise.com). These mismatched records will typically cause delays for DNS lookups. Additionally, the glue records for your private nameservers were pointed to different IPs than what was set at the registrar. I have set them to the following to match your registrar's expected setup:
>
> ns1.dxrise.com 174.121.38.188
>
> ns2.dxrise.com 174.121.38.189
>
> After making these changes, the site began loading in about three seconds with much of that time spent downloading the large scrolling banner images on the page. Please let us know if you are still experiencing slowness from your location so we can continue investigating this matter if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply extracted the files of drupal 7.7 on the root and it resolved the issue. that might be the permission issue which usually raise when we move drupal site from one server to another. actually this could have been resolved earlier but the support agent on web hosting site was denying that the site was moved from one location to another.